# Permutation of 'on' cells in a grid

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Given a $15\times15$ cell grid, how do you calculate the number of unique combinations of $N$ 'on' cells where an 'on' cell is checked off in some manner and $N$ is equal to $5$?

How does this calculation change if we say that cell $0,7$ is always 'on'. How many unique combinations of $N-1$ (where $N$ is $5$) could there be if we never include $0,7$?

Comment: Type \times to get $\times$.

Answer (score 1):

starting with the top left corner. And going to the right first. So the square in the row n and column $m$ has number $(n-1)15+m$. Then every combination can be given by a unique list of $15*15=225$ ones an zeroes. Where zero means off and 1 means on.

There are $2^{225}$ such lists. if they ask for a specific one of those numbers to be on or off then its $\frac{2^{225}}{2}=2^{224}$

So in reality this isn't a combination since you can repeat having something on or off. When you are allowed to repeat(If you had to choose one of them to be on and one of them to be off then it would be a combination). But in these cases its the same as making x digit numbers (in this case $225$) in a given base ( in this case 2).

---

So suppose N of these squares are locked on or off. Then you can only decide between the remaining 225-N cells. Then number them again and see that every combination is also determined by a number between 0 and 2^{225-N} base 2. That is there are 2^{225-N} choices. I recommend you read this wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positional_notation

Comment: Hmm, sorry, I just edited my question. What if only a subset would ever be marked on? For example 5 cells would always be marked on.

Comment: Um, so, if only 5 of the 15 were ever going to be marked on, that means 10 are always off - so would it be 2^25? and then if 1 was locked 2^24?

Comment: No, that can't be right because a 32x32 where 5 were on would be a bigger number...

Answer (score 0):

I'll help you out with just your first question. Note that there are exactly $2$ possible states for each cell: "on" or "off". Assuming that there are $15^2$ cells in a $15 \times 15$ grid, it follows by the [fundamental counting principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_counting_principle) that:
$$
N = 2^{15^2}=2^{225}
$$

Comment: But only 5 are on and 1 of those 5 will always be in the same position. That is what I was trying to get at.

Answer (score 0):

It's 5 choose 15^2

n choose k = is n!/(k!(n-k)!)

If one is locked it's 4 choose 224

Comment: Is this a solution to your own question (which is fine)?

Comment: that would be if you could only have 5 of them on or 4 of them on.